# JavaScript: How to reference an array inside an object inside an array and push something to it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reference, push

I have the following array:

```
var ships = [ { locations: [], hits:0 },
              { different: [], different1:0 },
              { different3: [], different2:0 } ];
```

How do I reference the array "locations" inside the 1st object and push something to it? Thanks!

Comment: ships[0].locations.push(foobar)

Comment: this will be a good read for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: @mihailm it would help us more if you shared more of your code. Are you looping over `ships`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use index access or Destructuring assignment

**Index access**

```js
var ships = [ { locations: [], hits:0 },
              { different: [], different1:0 },
              { different3: [], different2:0 } ];
              
ships[0].locations.push("Ele from SO");

console.log(ships)
```

**Destructuring assignment**

```js
var ships = [ { locations: [], hits:0 },
              { different: [], different1:0 },
              { different3: [], different2:0 } ];
              
var [obj] = ships;
obj.locations.push("Ele from SO");

console.log(ships)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
ships[0].locations.push(newItem);
```

Comment: A little explanation to the original poster (and future readers) is always going to make your answers better